# Booting issue with terminal

Tags: boot

When I start Ubuntu it go to terminal login page after I login it still for next command what I do next for boot
Please help

Comment: If you wish to *reboot*, you can use `sudo shutdown -r now`. If you're asking something different, please update your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you're running (1) whether this is a new installation or one you've used for a while (2) any error messages that you may see (3) any other information that might explain the problem 

Comment: Try command `startx`

Comment: Ohh thank you it's ok